# Cordova Hardware Access and Security

Tags: cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I'm wondering how Cordova is accessing the hardware of a device and in what security flaws this results?

I've studied the following architectural schema in the official cordova documentation, but somehow I lack of some understanding. 
Is it, that every OS ( Android, iOS, Fire, Windows Mobile...) APIs for the built in hardware delivers and Cordova is just implementing those in the background and providing seperate APIs for the dev to use?

Are there any sources on how cordova uses for example the gyroscope and the camera?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX8un.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jb7e.png)

Answer (score 0):

All the plugins and platforms are open source

[Camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

[Device motion](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion)